# Logging in spring integration

Tags: java, logging, spring-integration

i have API's built in springintegration to call a third party soap services. My API's are called from camel services and sends json request and receives json response. This code was developed almost 4 years back and no logging mechanism has been provided.  Now i have to implement logging for every request from camel services and response to camel services. is there any mechanism provided in spring intergration which will be helpfull or i have to implment basic logging by using log4j.. Kindly help

i was sudying many options on google but none of them were clear

Answer (score 0):

Would be great to see some code for more specific place to inject, but from general perspective Spring Integration provides a `<logging-channel-adapter>` to log messages on the channel. Together with the `<wire-tap>` on channels (can be global) yo cal log almost all the messages in your flows.

More info is in the Docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/#logging-channel-adapter

On the other hand you are mentioning SOAP I hope you do that using Spring WS project and appropriate channel adapters from Spring Integration. Anyway there is hook in Spring WS to log SOAP requests and responses: https://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/docs/3.0.7.RELEASE/reference/#logging